# Find rows with specific string inside column text

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in working with SQL Server and I'm trying to select all rows which has a specific string inside a column.
The field has a big string of characters, for example:

> 0x8F28EA0000000000000094EFFF00275F0A7F000**0F86FFF00**275EF57F0000

I tried using the simple

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE COLUMN LIKE '%0F86FFF00%'
```

But as I have read that SQL Server doesn't have this syntax so how could I do it differently but get the same result?

Comment: WHERE [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186323%28v%3dsql.105%29)('0F86FFF00',COLUMN) > 0

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: If it's varbinary: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=6ab8726d4b4b7bbe2999c05242290669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column is most likely of the `VARBINARY` data type, so it's ***visual representation*** starts with `0x` and displays hex characters (from 0 to F). You can't simply use `LIKE` against a `VARBINARY` column, since `LIKE` operates with string data types like `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`.

You can convert your `VARBINARY` to the string you are seeing by using `CONVERT` with the 3rd parameter as 1, check this example:

```
DECLARE @Varbinary VARBINARY(MAX) = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'This is my string value.')

SELECT
    OriginalRepresentation = @Varbinary,
    ConvertToString = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Varbinary),
    ConvertToStringHex = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @Varbinary, 1)
```

Result:

```
OriginalRepresentation                              ConvertToString             ConvertToStringHex
0x54686973206973206D7920737472696E672076616C75652E  This is my string value.    0x54686973206973206D7920737472696E672076616C75652E
```

If you are using SSMS, when you query a `VARBINARY` column, SSMS is automatically converting your `VARBINARY` to the hex-string representation so it's "interpretable" to the user.

So to correctly filter using `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [COLUMN], 1) LIKE '%0F86FFF00%'
```

Comment: You could also use style 2 (instead of 1), to have output without the `0x`.